# how give max width according to screen flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: Here is web application image]

[image: Here is mobile applicatio image]

as you can mobile screen width is maxed to width
but in web application it's not streached to max width

Please check this
github link---https://github.com/dhaval7152/demohouse.git

I am new in flutter

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: checkout this link,there are multiple way to create resonsvie app,https://medium.com/flutter-community/develop-a-responsive-layout-of-mobile-app-with-flutter-c6a6f7013aec#:~:text=Responsive%20design%20simply%20means%20using,and%20shape%20of%20the%20device.   and  https://aloisdeniel.com/#/posts/adaptative-ui      also checkout this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil

Comment: I tried all method none of working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Container(
  // this is the width of the screen
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Scaffold(...);
),
```